# C++ Debug with unexpected arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging, cmake, command-line-arguments

I used CMake to build the projekt.
When I run with Debug, I got always others unexpected arguments.

why there're such arguments, although I didn't input these arguments.

```
argv:2>CON
argv:1>CON
argv:<CON
```

Actuall arguments:
run in terminal

```
C:\Code\HGS-CVRP\HGS-CVRP\build>"C:/Code/HGS-CVRP/HGS-CVRP/build/hgs.exe" ../Instances/CVRP/X-n157-k13.vrp mySolution.sol -seed 1 -t 30
argc:7
argv:C:/Code/HGS-CVRP/HGS-CVRP/build/hgs.exe
argv:../Instances/CVRP/X-n157-k13.vrp
argv:mySolution.sol
argv:-seed
argv:1
argv:-t
argv:30
```

When I run with Debug

```
argc:10
argv:C:\Code\HGS-CVRP\HGS-CVRP\build\hgs.exe
argv:../Instances/CVRP/X-n157-k13.vrp
argv:mySolution.sol
argv:-seed
argv:1
argv:-t
argv:30
argv:2>CON
argv:1>CON
argv:<CON
```

launch.json

````
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            // Resolved by CMake Tools:
            "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
            "args": [
            "../Instances/CVRP/X-n157-k13.vrp",
            "mySolution.sol",
            "-seed",
            "1", 
            "-t",
            "30"
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [
                {
                    // add the directory where our target was built to the PATHs
                    // it gets resolved by CMake Tools:
                    "name": "PATH",
                    "value": "${env:PATH}:${command:cmake.getLaunchTargetDirectory}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "OTHER_VALUE",
                    "value": "Something something"
                }
            ],
        
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}```
````

```
// Reads the line of command and extracts possible options
CommandLine(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc % 2 != 1 || argc > 35 || argc < 3)
    {
        std::cout << "----- NUMBER OF COMMANDLINE ARGUMENTS IS INCORRECT: " << argc << std::endl;
        display_help();
        throw std::string("Incorrect line of command");
    }
    else
    {
        pathInstance = std::string(argv[1]);
        pathSolution = std::string(argv[2]);
        for (int i = 3; i < argc; i += 2)
        {
            if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-t")
                ap.timeLimit = atof(argv[i + 1]);
            else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-it")
                ap.nbIter = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-seed")
                ap.seed = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-veh")
                nbVeh = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-round")
                isRoundingInteger = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-log")
                verbose = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-nbGranular")
                ap.nbGranular = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-mu")
                ap.mu = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-lambda")
                ap.lambda = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-nbElite")
                ap.nbElite = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-nbClose")
                ap.nbClose = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-nbIterPenaltyManagement")
                ap.nbIterPenaltyManagement = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-nbIterTraces")
                ap.nbIterTraces = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-targetFeasible")
                ap.targetFeasible = atof(argv[i + 1]);
            else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-penaltyIncrease")
                ap.penaltyIncrease = atof(argv[i + 1]);
            else if (std::string(argv[i]) == "-penaltyDecrease")
                ap.penaltyDecrease = atof(argv[i + 1]);
            else
            {
                std::cout << "----- ARGUMENT NOT RECOGNIZED: " << std::string(argv[i]) << std::endl;
                display_help();
                throw std::string("Incorrect line of command");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: CMake should not be involved in the execution of your program or the debugger arguments.

Comment: sounds like this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4239#issuecomment-1452743997. what version of the C++ extension do you have installed?

Comment: thank you so much starball that you found this similar solution. 

Comment: thanks, `"avoidWindowsConsoleRedirection": true` in `launch.json`seemed to have done the trick.

Comment: or you can set `"externalConsole": true`